# Сколько сможет выдержать сервер?

Tags: веб-сервер, сервер

Здравствуйте, у меня вопрос, я заказал VPS вот с такими характеристиками

```
ПроцессорQuad-Core AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 2386 SE 1203.175 MhzОперативная память3145728 kBРазмер дискового пространства10240 MbСредняя загрузка0.05 0.06 0.01
```

Может ли он выдержать человек 500 в день, которые будут активно использовать mysql (вся работа будет проводится с помощью AJAX)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сервер включает

- 4 ядра,
- 3 Гб памяти,
- 10 Гб диска

Этих ресурсов заведомо достаточно для обычного веб-сервера типа LAMP при посещаемости много большей, чем 500 человек в день. Практически всегда узким местом веб-сервера является база данных, но поскольку запас памяти велик, наверняка при работе с базой данных будет использоваться кэширование в памяти, что ускоряет работу.

Указанные параметры вполне позволят обработать и 5000 человек в день и больше, в зависимости от того, что они будут делать на сайте. Вообще всегда есть смысл для начала приобрести минимальный тариф и наращивать его по мере роста посещаемости.